# How to make running total for datagridview with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I go this problem on how to make a running total in a datagridview with a multiple conditions.

I had this table compose of columns 'Bal' that makes the running total and the columns 'Balance' that copies the amount of fees if the payment is enough, if you would mind to look at the image below for your reference:

[image: Sample Result]

Here is the case: if the amount of payment is enough to pay the values in the values under column `Amount`, then it will copy the values of column `Amount` and paste it into column `Balance`.

But if not enough to pay the amount of fee to the next row, It will show the difference under columns `Balance`.

I have tried this code but, it does not meet the required condition, although it works fine.

```
 Dim Bal As Decimal = 0
    Dim i As Integer
    With dgvSTSub
        .Rows(i).Cells("Bal").Value = CurrencyTextBoxAmount.Text
    End With

    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvSTSub.Rows

        Bal = Bal + r.Cells(3).Value - r.Cells(1).Value
        r.Cells(3).Value = Bal

        If r.Cells(1).Value > r.Cells(2).Value Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = r.Cells(1).Value
        ElseIf Bal < 0 Then
            r.Cells(2).Value = Bal - bal - 1
        End If
    Next
```

Please help me with this, I'm really stuck here.

Comment: What does this question have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: Where did the data come from?   Is that Payment column/item really a column and not a row?  There may be a very easy way to do what you want, but we cant tell what the data store looks like from that.

Comment: The Columns "Fee" and "Amount" in the datagridview is databounded with sqlserver table..The rest of the columns are not, they only make the computation which was presented above. I just want to know how to achieve this computation with the code i provided..Please help